# Excel | Remove last part of string by delimiter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a big Excel Table. There are URL-Paths without the base-url at the start and i want to remove the last part of the string.

For Example:

I have some URL like this:

- /thisis/an/example/path

And i want it to be like this:

- /thisis/an/example

Is there a Formula for this or how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a go with:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=TEXTBEFORE(A1,"/",-1)
```